# Add an external filter in vue-table-2

Tags: vue.js, vue-tables-2

Anyone please help me with the code to add an external filter in vue-table-2.
I tried using slots

```html
<div slot="filter__id">
    <input type="input" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "external filter" here?

Comment: filter box outside the table. A search box is found outside the table which filters data from all fields. I have to make different search boxes for different field data searching. For eg: search box with a placeholder "search name", typing in this box showing filtered rows based on name search

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `filterable` to `true` in the options you are passing to the table and then this slot will start working.